# VueJS computed return best practice

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, foreach

I've using this code over and over again. Wonder if there's a better way to make this shortcut

Here's the example

```
// items.js

export default [
  { title: 'ABC', href: 'javascript:void(0)' },
  { title: 'DEF', href: 'javascript:void(0)' }
]
```

```
// index.vue

<script>
import items from './items.js'
export default: {
  computed: {
    links() {
      let results = []
      items.forEach((item,index) => {
        item.id = index

        results.push(item)
      })
      return results
    }
  }
}
</script>

//returned result = { title: 'ABC', href: 'javascript:void(0)', id: 0 }
```

I just want to add id to each of the object in the computed property, so that I not worry about using `v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"`. instead just using `v-for="item in links" :key="item.id"` in the template

The question:

1. From the code, you see I declare empty array of results `let results = []` then I populate the result from forEach data before I return the result. Is that any better way to do to return each of the loop data without declare empty array and populate it before return the array of that generated data?
2. Sometimes, I not just add id, maybe add another like `item.internal = true`. Or level if it's multilevel.

Comment: Is this the only use for the `id` property?  You're essentially just trading one variable name for another, and introducing unneeded complexity and probably something you will revert down the road anyway.

Comment: Also since `items` never changes, there's not much reason to make it a `computed` property.  Better off putting the `links` in `data()` and doing the assignment/mapping in `mounted()`.

Comment: Essentially just an ID, but some of them need more.., if there's a child I need initial showchild = false, internal data, need to convert date format &etc

Comment: What else are you using the `id` property for?  If the only reason is to have a unique value for the v-for key, you're best off doing it as before in the v-for.  You can still map in that extra data if you needed when the component is mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map` method and spread operator to add `id` to the `item` :

```
 computed: {
    links() {
       return  items.map((item,index)=>({id:index,...item}))
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this work. May I know is there anyway to map multi-level. Example the data: `{ title: 'ABC', href: 'javascript:void(0)', child: [ title: 'XYZ' ] }`. Also it is able to perform if,else logic inside map?

Comment: you could do that `items.map((item,index)=>({id:index,child: [ {title: 'XYZ' }] ,...item}))`